# How to display formdetails in horizontal mode?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display labels with BS3 next to the values. At the moment the label is above the actual value:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="">Account</label>

    <p>{{orderDetails.accountId}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="">Accounttype</label>

    <p>{{orderDetails.accountType}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="">Accountname</label>

    <p>{{orderDetails.accountName}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I get the label Account with below it the value. I would like to get the value to the right. Which bootstrap class do I use?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `p` tag use `span` tag both will be in same line.

- https://jsfiddle.net/v7k770th/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove p tag from this. p tag is moving it to the next line.
Even if it doesn't solve problem. Move data( without p tag) inside label tag and you will have your desired look. In this case for styling data you should use span tag for data.